# On Closing of Browser,Call Server Side Function then Display Alert Message

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events, .net-1.1

My requirement is when I close the browser, I have to delete a record from a database and if during this deletion process, if any `Exception` raises then show alert and don't close the browser.

My code is:

```
 <body  onbeforeunload="javascript:return unlockOperationonMain()"></body>
function unlockOperationonMain()
    {

                    top.welcomePage.__doPostBack('Close', 'ApplicationInstance')
                     return '';
    }

function unloadFunction()
    {

                    deleteCookie();
    }
```

I am using .net 1.1. Problems I am facing is that when an `Exception` raises, there is an additional dialog box comes and asks

> "DO You really want to navigate Press Ok to Continue and Cancel to.."

I don't want this dialog box to come because in this dialog box if I press OK browser closes, but I have to show an alert and don't close the page in case of `Exception`.

Comment: What action do you want to take when the user clicks the browser "Close" button? What do you want to do when the user shits down the machine? When he just turns the power off?

Comment: Also, BTW, you need to learn HTML. Your code doesn't work at all. You have no content in the `body`, and your script isn't in a script block

Comment: @John,I have removed Content of Body...

Comment: What is required that When I close the browser,I have to perform some server side functions(deleting a record from database). If any exception occurs during this deletion process I have to show an alert message "Operation Unsuccessful" and in that case the browser should not close.

Comment: @John,dont bother about My script block and HTML,also I have to do only handle close button of browser.Its not about shits down :P

Answer (score 4):

Using JavaScript page-onunload to perform a server-end/database operation **isn't reliable**.

**There is no way** to override browser behaviour to force the user to stay on the page. If that were possible, there would be a lot of really frustrated users! You should use some other methodology to remove the database entry (sessions and their invalidation perhaps?)